# How to immediately stop decoding in GPUImage?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpuimage

We decoding MP4-compressed video with mask embedded using GPUImageMovie.

Problem that if user presses Home button during video decoding - the app became crashed because of OpenGL trap. iOS does not allow to use OpenGL in background.

Is there any way to tell GPUImageMovie to stop decoding immediately, including video thread?

Answer (score 1):

You should listen for UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification and UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification in the view controller where you are processing the movie:

```
// handles the user pressing the home or power button while the camera is onscreen
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didResignActive:)
                                             name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(willEnterForeground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then you should add the appropriate methods to respond to the notifications:

```
-(void) didResignActive: (NSString *) notification {
    //stop processing the movie
}

-(void) willEnterForeground: (NSString *) notification {
    // start processing the movie
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can start processing by calling `[movie startProcessing];` and stop processing with `[movie endProcessing];` but I'm not positive.